# Changing the height of a container dynamically

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard

[image]

I'm trying to dynamically change the height of the container to match the height of the table view. I'm currently trying to do it with `prepareForSegue()` in Newsfeed View Controller. However `newsfeedContainer.frame.height = 10` doesn't work.

Edit: I'm trying to edit the constraint. I get the following error with the following code.

Error: `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION`

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "NewsfeedSegue" {
            print("NewsfeedSegue Triggered")
            var newsfeedTableController: NewsfeedTableViewController?
            newsfeedTableController = segue.destinationViewController as? NewsfeedTableViewController
            if newsfeedTableController != nil {
                containerHeightConstraint.constant = newsfeedTableController!.newsfeedTableView.frame.height
            }
        }
    }
```

Edit 2: I did it using the following code in the table view controller's `viewDidLoad()`

```
let viewController = parentViewController as? NewsfeedViewController
        viewController?.containerHeightConstraint.constant = newsfeedTableView.frame.height
```

Comment: Use view did layout subviews and set the height. If you are using constraints, add an outlet to the constraint and change the constant.

Comment: Have you tried lowering the vertical compression resistance priority on the container in interface builder?

Comment: @Brandon I'm trying to set the constraint but I think I'm getting an error while getting the height of the table. Please see edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using AutoLayout (and you almost certainly are; it's the default) then changing a view's frame usually doesn't work. As soon as something triggers a layout update, the constraints (either ones you specify or system-genrated constraints) take over and reset the frame to its previous values.

As Brandon says in his comment, if you're using AutoLayout you need to add one or more constraints, make those constraints outlets, and then change the constant value of the constraint.

Comment: Yes I have AutoLayout on. I started setting up a system to set the constraint. When I try and use viewController.frame.height on the TableView I get the error I put in the edit.

Comment: You can't (and shouldn't) manipulate outlets from prepareForSegue or from outside the view controller. Instead, you should add a property to the destination VC, and the set the constraint in viewDidLoad.

Comment: How do I go about getting an IBOutlet for the container in the Table Controller?